# XML Schematron validation using .net core

Tags: .net-core, schematron

I would like to implement XML Schematron validation using .net core.

Is there any .net core implementation or .net core library exists for XML Schematron validation ?

I am working on the following solution "https://github.com/thebecwar/nc-schematron".

Because this  version doesn't support many XLST function e.g [current](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_current.asp)()...

Comment: Have you found any solution ? I have some XML files that has in some rules so XML document that I need validate against that rules.

Comment: any solutions on these?